# React 16 upgrade .. Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ReactMount'

Tags: reactjs

On an upgrade from React 15 to React 16 I'm getting:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ReactMount'

For I think most if not all my components. What is the fix for this?

If its relevant I am using an old version of react-router@2.8.1

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#packaging There is no react/lib/* anymore according to doc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using React Hot Loader 1.x, stop using it.

It won't work with React 16.

Comment: Can't use RHL3, because it doesn't work with HOCs (although there is an issue for this bug) -> can't use React16 :(

Answer (score 1):

In React 16 no react/lib/* and react-dom/lib/*