# Migration to React 16.0.0 Error: Cannot find module "react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to migrate from `react 15.6.1` to `16.0.0`. I have updated my package.json, to `"react": "16.0.0","react-dom": "16.0.0",` (only things I changed so far), and from what I've understood from the changelogs, things should have gone smoothly. But they don't! From what I understand, they removed the `/lib` part in the `v16.0.0`, hence why the module cannot be found?

Am I missing something obvious? [image]Would appreciate any help! :)

Comment: Please check comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46445723/2315280)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have two copies of React loaded.
Try this in your terminal:

```
npm ls react
```

And also:

```
npm ls react-dom
```

If either of these commands shows more than one result, then you have two copies of React, and **that is not supported**.

Delete all copies except the ones in the root `node_modules`, and file an issue with projects that specify React as a `dependency`. It must be a `peerDependency` so that a situation like this doesn't occur.